# Show error message if wrong subnet

Tags: c#

I have subnet scanner, what scans your network and you can see running processes.

I have problem now, I must search subnet with 192.168.0 but if someone buts 192.168.0.1 how to give error message?

At the moment program crashes for that.

My code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
{
    string subnetn = "." + i.ToString();
    myPing = new Ping();
    reply = myPing.Send(subnet + subnetn, 10); //Here it throws error. {"An exception occurred during a Ping request."}
    MetroMessageBox.Show(Owner, "Problem " + reply.ToString() + " .", "Ended", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    StaatuseTeave.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    StaatuseTeave.Text = "Scanning..   - " + subnet + subnetn;
```

Or how I can do if he trying 192.168.0.1 it starts also scan correctly?

Comment: simple answer would be validate your input..  how would  you handle a subnet thats say /30 ? how would you tell it apart from someone typing in an IP?

Comment: @BugFinder I didnt think about that. But it just starts scan fast whole network.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = subnet.Split('.');
if (array.Length != 3)
{
    //show error message
}
```

Comment: Yes gives error message correctly. But it also crashes here `reply = myPing.Send(subnet + subnetn, 10); //Here it throws error. {"An exception occurred during a Ping request."}` if I close error message.

Comment: Whilst code only answers may provide a solution to the question, some form of explanation would help in making this a more useful answer.